# Mockito and Junit tests run in isolation but fail when run together

Tags: junit, mockito

I have been encountering a strange issue. My test cases have one failing test, the `welcometest`. However, if I run the same in isolation, it runs perfectly. I am new to `JUnit` and have no idea why this could happen.

```
package com.twu.biblioteca;

org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before; 
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;


public class ExampleTest {
    @Test
    public void welcometest() {
        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
        test.welcome(asker);
        verify(asker).printLine("**** Welcome Customer! We are glad to have you at Biblioteca! ****");
    }

    @Test
    public void addBooksTest() {
        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
        test.addBooks();

        assertEquals("Head First Java", test.booksList[1].name);
        assertEquals("Dheeraj Malhotra", test.booksList[2].author);
        assertEquals(2009, test.booksList[3].publication);
    }

    @Test
    public void CustomersaddedTest() {
        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
        test.addCustomers();

        assertEquals("Ritabrata Moitra", test.customerList[1].name);
        assertEquals("121-1523", test.customerList[2].libraryNumber);
        assertEquals("0987654321", test.customerList[3].number);
    }

    @Test
    public void addMoviesTest() {
        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
        test.addMovies();

        assertEquals("Taken", test.moviesList[1].name);
        assertEquals("Steven Spielberg", test.moviesList[2].director);
        assertEquals(2004, test.moviesList[3].year);
    }


    @Test
    public void getBoundIntegerFromUserTest() {
        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
        when(asker.ask("Enter your choice. ")).thenReturn(99);
        when(asker.ask("Select a valid option! ")).thenReturn(1);

        BibliotecaApp.getBoundIntegerFromUser(asker, "Enter your choice. ", 1, 2);

        verify(asker).ask("Select a valid option! ");
    }

    @Test
    public void mainMenuTest() {
        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
        when(asker.ask("Enter your choice. ")).thenReturn(test.numberOfMainMenuOptions);

        test.mainMenu(asker);

        verify(test).mainMenuaction(3, asker);
    }

    @Test
    public void checkoutTest() {
        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
        when(asker.ask("Enter the serial number of the book that you want to checkout")).thenReturn(2);

        test.addBooks();
        test.checkout(asker);

        assertEquals(0, test.booksList[2].checkoutstatus);
    }

    @Test
    public void returnTest() {
        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
        when(asker.ask("Enter the serial number of the book that you want to return")).thenReturn(2);

        test.addBooks();
        test.booksList[2].checkoutstatus = 0;
        test.returnBook(asker);

        assertEquals(1, test.booksList[2].checkoutstatus);
    }

    @Test
    public void checkoutMovieTest() {
        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
        when(asker.ask("Enter the serial number of the movie that you want to checkout")).thenReturn(2);

        test.addMovies();
        test.checkoutMovie(asker);

        assertEquals(0, test.moviesList[2].checkoutstatus);
    }

    @Test
    public void returnMovieTest() {
        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
        when(asker.ask("Enter the serial number of the movie that you want to return")).thenReturn(2);

        test.addMovies();
        test.moviesList[2].checkoutstatus = 0;
        test.returnMovie(asker);

        assertEquals(1, test.moviesList[2].checkoutstatus);
    }

//    @Test
//    public void checkoutWithoutLoginTest(){
//        BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
//        BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker =          mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
//        when(asker.ask("Enter your choice. ")).thenReturn(8);
//        test.loginStatus = false;
//
//
//        test.mainMenuaction(3,asker);
//
//        verify(test,times(0)).checkout(asker);
//    }
}
```

If I comment out the last test (that is already commented out) all my tests run successfully! However if I do not comment it out, one test fails but that is not this test! It is the `welcometest` that fails!

Comment: why are you mocking your class under test ? (BibliotecaApp)

Answer (score 0):

```
 BibliotecaApp test = mock(BibliotecaApp.class);
 BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker asker = mock(BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker.class);
 test.welcome(asker);
 verify(asker).printLine("**** Welcome Customer! We are glad to have you at Biblioteca! ****");
```

1. Create a MOCK BibliotecaApp
2. Create a MOCK BibliotecaApp.IntegerAsker
3. Run the `method` welcome on the MOCK with a MOCK as a parameter
4. Expect that your MOCK did call another method.

Question: Why should it do that? You never told it to. Your `test` object will return `null` and not call any `printLine` method.

So, personally, I highly doubt that this test will ever run successfully, in isolation or otherwise. It also doesn't make any sense, since you are testing the behavior of a mock object. But we can assume that Mockito itself is already tested fairly well. You (probably) need to use a real `BibliotecaApp` instead of a Mock.

Comment: Using a real Biblioteca app did the trick for me! Thank youi!